# Using CEDET in emacs 24.3.1

Tags: emacs, elisp, cedet

I learned that CEDET comes built in emacs 24.3.1 which I have installed.
Unfortunately, all tutorials online instruct you to install CEDET and provide you with config files that refer and load the installed packages and files.

How is it possible to configure the built in CEDET and use it without any external installation?
I am not sure how to take advantage of the built in version.

Answer (score 1):

It's circa Emacs 23, but Alex Ott's [A Gentle Introduction to CEDET](http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsCedet.html) still looks relevant to the built-in version? (it covers both versions).

Comment: Thanks for the response phils. I did actually read that article but it keeps referring to the "stand alone" version of CEDET. I am yet to find a configuration file or set of instructions that applies to the bundled version only.

Comment: From article: "This article describes new version of CEDET, including version bundled with GNU Emacs." ;-) Following config, mentioned in article, should work for built-in CEDET: https://gist.github.com/alexott/3930120

Comment: Alex, thanks for the response. I did actually use this .el package you linked. But again it needed these packages:
(setq cedet-root-path (file-name-as-directory "~/projects/cedet-bzr/"))
(load-file (concat cedet-root-path "cedet-devel-load.el"))
(add-to-list 'load-path (concat cedet-root-path "contrib")).

I guess I will have to read the article you recommended to install the missing pieces.

Comment: Alex, I downloaded and installed cedet-1.1 but could not find the file cedet-devel-load.el that you refer to in both of your config files:minimial-cedet-config.el and emacs-rc-cedet.el. Any pointers?